# EF Sum between 3 tables

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Say we got a Database design like this.

```
Customer
Id  Name
1   John
2   Jack

Order
Id  CustomerId
1   1
2   1
3   2

OrderLine
Id  OrderId  ProductId Quantity
1   1        1         10
2   1        2         20
3   2        1         30
4   3        1         10
```

How would I create an entity framework query to calculate the total Quantity a given Customer has ordered of a given Product?

```
Input => CustomerId = 1 & ProductId = 1
Output => 40
```

This is what I got so far, through its not complete and still missing the Sum.

```
var db = new ShopTestEntities();
        var orders = db.Orders;
        var details = db.OrderDetails;

        var query = orders.GroupJoin(details,
            order => order.CustomerId,
            detail => detail.ProductId,
            (order, orderGroup) => new
                                   {
                                       CustomerID = order.CustomerId,
                                       OrderCount = orderGroup.Count()
                                   });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find it's easier to use the special Linq syntax as opposed to the extension method style when I'm doing joins and groupings, so I hope you don't mind if I write it in that style.

This is the first approach that comes to mind for me:

```
int customerId = 1;
int productId = 1;
var query = from orderLine in db.OrderLines
            join order in db.Orders on orderLine.OrderId equals order.Id
            where order.CustomerId == customerId && orderLine.ProductId == productId
            group orderLine by new { order.CustomerId, orderLine.ProductId } into grouped
            select grouped.Sum(g => g.Quantity);

// The result will be null if there are no entries for the given product/customer.
int? quantitySum = query.SingleOrDefault();
```

I can't check what kind of SQL this will generate at the moment, but I think it should be something pretty reasonable. I did check that it gave the right result when using Linq To Objects.